# Simple UNIX case statement

Tags: unix, if-statement, case

I'm trying to allow a user to be able to input an "i" or a "v" and have different messages echo

Here's my code:

```
 while getopts :iv opt
 do
   case $opt in
           i)  interactive=true ;;
           v)  verbose=true ;;
          \?) echo "$0: invalid option --'$OPTARG'"
               exit  ;;
      esac
 done
 shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

So far it works, but I'm not sure how to call it outside of this loop.

Should I use an if loop? Please Help!

Comment: By Unix do you mean POSIX compliant sh?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't inherit environment variables `interactive` and `verbose` by setting them to a value before the loop.

```
interactive=false
verbose=false
while getopts :iv opt
do ...
done
```

The code you show will recognize command line options `-i` or `-v` or combinations thereof and set the variables accordingly.

You can then make the code after the loop do different things depending on the values of `$interactive` and `$verbose`.  Note that these tests assume that the variables are set to either `true` or `false` (strings); they won't work properly if the variables are empty.

```
if [ $interactive = true ]
then read line
     ...process $line...
fi

if [ $verbose = true ]
then echo "Talking more than usual..."
fi
```

Etc.

I'm not sure what 'how to call it outside of this loop' means.